# Trigger a new asynchronous operation from a canceled completion handler

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Is it semantically valid to initiate from a completion handler which received a "boost::asio::error::operation_canceled" a new asynchronous operation on the same I/O-object, or should one consider the I/O-object as "invalid" and perform corresponding business-logic?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try {
        boost::asio::io_context io_context;

        // Create a UDP socket and bind it to a local endpoint.
        boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_context);
        boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint local_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 54321);
        socket.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());

        int var;
        socket.bind(local_endpoint);

        std::vector<std::uint8_t> buffer(100);
        socket.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buffer.data(), buffer.size()), [&socket, &buffer](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t len)
                             {
                                 if (!ec) {
                                     std::cout << "1: UDP-Server: no. of bytes received: " << len << std::endl;
                                 } else if (ec == std::errc::operation_canceled) {
                                     // Is it semantically valid???
                                     socket.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buffer.data(), buffer.size()),
                                                          [&socket, &buffer](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t len) {

                                                          });
                                 }
                             });

        socket.cancel();
        io_context.run();

    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Unexpected exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the IO object as well as the [nature of the cancellation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/cancellation_type.html):

- terminal
  Requests cancellation where, following a successful cancellation, the only safe operations on the I/O object are closure or destruction.
- partial
  Requests cancellation where a successful cancellation may result in partial side effects or no side effects. Following cancellation, the I/O object is in a well-known state, and may be used for further operations.
- total
  Requests cancellation where a successful cancellation results in no apparent side effects. Following cancellation, the I/O object is in the same observable state as it was prior to the operation.

E.g. The following is trivially valid:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/WKEx8GsvE)**

[image]

### Complicated Examples

In more complicated IO objects, look at the documented cancellation support, e.g. read operations on `asio::ssl::stream<asio::ip::tcp::socket>`, first refer [to `ssl::stream<>::async_read_some`](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/async_read_some.html#boost_asio.reference.ssl__stream.async_read_some.per_operation_cancellation):

> #### Per-Operation Cancellation This asynchronous operation supports cancellation for the following cancellation_type values:
>
> - `cancellation_type::terminal`
> - `cancellation_type::partial`
>
> if they are also supported by the `Stream` type's `async_read_some`
> and `async_write_some` operations.

As you can see you it defers to the support of the underlying `ip::tcp::socket` type, which in our case supports both: https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html#boost_asio.reference.basic_stream_socket.async_read_some.per_operation_cancellation

### Implied Cancellations

There are a number of situations where operation cancellation can be implied.

- One would be when the object is destructed. In well-designed code it would be hard to accidentally initiate new operations after that point, either because a smart pointer become `nullptr` or because the initiation would need to be actually *inside* a destructor. This kind of mistake is easy enough to spot during a code review.
- Some object-specific operations like `tcp::socket::close()` or [changing the expiration](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/expires_after.html) on a timer object. In both cases it is technically possible to initiate new operations on the same object, and what happens depends on the object documentation, e.g.
- most operations on a socket would fail after `close()` (i.e. complete with  an errorcode like `error::bad_descriptor`)
- other operations are documented to open the socket if required (e.g. [`async_connect`](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_connect.html))

Comment: Thank you for this extensive response. I will need some time to understand all that in detail in the hope to fix the following AZMQ-related issue correctly: https://github.com/zeromq/azmq/issues/210.
The question is, why does AZMQ perform the invocation of the completion handler synchronously and doesn't post the completion handlers?

Comment: Oh. That's a very different question. The deadlock is the least of your worries. The question is "is AZMQ allowed to call handlers outside service threads?" - The answer is NO: [_"Asynchronous completion handlers will only be called from threads that are currently calling io_context::run()"_](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html#:~:text=Asynchronous%20completion%20handlers%20will%20only%20be%20called%20from%20threads%20that%20are%20currently%20calling%20io_context%3A%3Arun()). This means AZMQ violates the Asio contracts.

Comment: FWIW I tried with the undocumented( `azmqsocket.set_option(azmq::socket::allow_speculative(false))` but no difference.

Comment: It seems to work if one removes the invocation of "cancel_ops(impl);" in line 483 in module "socket_service.hpp". Doing so, the functor "reactor_handler" will be executed with an "operation_aborted" in context of the "io_context::run()" call due to canceled "demultiplexer" (i.e. calling "impl->cancel_stream_descriptor(ec);"). IMO, this seems then to be equivalent to the "asio"-way how pending operations get canceled if one compares it with the "cancel_ops" function in "epoll_reactor.ipp". Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Oof. I'm always very anxious of "simple fixes" like this. I looked at the implementation briefly yesterday, and I fear that the design flaw runs deeper, in that if you remove `cancel_ops` it runs into life-time issues (UB) because the descriptor. Regardless, the executor invocation rules are NOT honored: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/W83xMGqve (my output https://imgur.com/a/Qo6IkNs)

Comment: Ok. I will take a closer look and initiate an internal review: Curious what my colleagues will catch/find related to my proposed solution - hopefully no indication for an UB.
As for the rules for calling executors: that's beyond my boost::Asio knowledge-> just too complex for me at the moment. Anyway, thank you so far for these valuable hints!